# Laravel 4 localhost status 500

Tags: laravel, mamp

I pushed (bitbucket) a laravel 4 project from my imac and pulled it with another mac. What I get is a status 500 message if i try to visit /public.
I am using MAMP.

The strange thing is that every other laravel project is working fine. One project is even a copy of the project that doesn't work.

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Point Apache to a `public` directory instead of root one and use URLs without `public` in it.

Restart web server after that to make it work.

Comment: Any idea why all the other laravel projects are working?

Comment: No, because it's the wrong way to use Laravel, I never did it. When you're trying to reinvent the wheel, you should be ready to get a bunch of strange errors.